# How to ignore 'search' key press in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialog, android-keypad, android-dialogfragment

I was previously extending the `Dialog` class for my dialogs and I had to use the following code segment in my dialogs so that they would not be dismissed when the phone's *search* key was pressed:

```
setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
{
  public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH)
      return true; // pretend we've processed it
    else
      return false; // pass on to be processed as normal
  }
});
```

I am now using the `DialogFragment` class for my dialogs. Unfortunately `DialogFragment` has the same problem as `Dialog` in that dialogs are dismissed when the phone's *search* key is pressed (regardless of the dialog's cancelable state). Doubly problematic is that `DialogFragment` does not have a `setOnKeyListener` method so the above code segment no longer applies.

Anyone know how I can get my dialogs (when showing) to ignore *search* key presses?

> **Note:** I tried adding the above code segment to my activity's `onKeyUp`
>   method but unfortunately my activity's `onKeyUp` method is not called
>   if a `DialogFragment` instance is showing. Instead, irritatingly, the
>   `DialogFragment` instance is dismissed.

Comment: try to put your code in fragment activity class. I hope with fragment activity your code will work

Comment: No joy. See note added to question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this.
Inside your `DialogFragment.Onresume`

```
 getDialog().setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
 {
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH)
      return true; // pretend we've processed it
    else
      return false; // pass on to be processed as normal
  }
});
```

Comment: Great answer! I was trying to find a solution for Adil Hussain but just when I was about to post a similar solution you posted it!

Comment: Sweet. Thanks nandeesh. I didn't realise there was a `getDialog()` method. I thought the `DialogFragment` _was_ the dialog!